# parsing values into array

Tags: arrays, perl, bash

I have a simple question, I think, but I can't find the solution for it.
A simple perl script prints out following line `"tests - Blub" "tests - Blub - Abc"` and I assign it to a variable like that `var=$(perl ...)`, but why can't I parse it to an array with `varArray=( $var )` and that command `varArray=( "tests - Blub" "tests - Blub - Abc" )` works?

The expected result should be like this:

```
tests - Blub
tests - Blub - Abc
```

And not like this:

```
"tests
-
Blub"
"tests
-
Blub
-
Abc"
```

Thanks for any advices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's some doodling:

```
$ bash
$ a='"tests - Blub" "tests - Blub - Abc"'
$ ary=( $a ); echo ${#ary[@]}
8
$ ary=( "$a" ); echo ${#ary[@]}
1
$ eval ary=( $a ); echo ${#ary[@]}
2
```

Clearly the 3rd result is what you want. When you populate your variable from the output of the Perl script, the double quotes within it have no special meaning to the shell: they're just characters.  You have to get the shell to parse it (with `eval`) so that their meaning is exposed.

Answer (score 1):

I did the following:

```
$ cat >/tmp/test.sh
echo '"tests - Blub" "tests - Blub - Abc"'

$ chmod +x /tmp/test.sh

$ /tmp/test.sh
"tests - Blub" "tests - Blub - Abc"

$ a=`/tmp/test.sh`

$ echo $a
"tests - Blub" "tests - Blub - Abc"

$ arr=($a)

$ echo $arr[1]
"tests[1]
```

This tells me that () construct ignores double quotes after variable expansions. Moreover, when I do

```
for i in $a; do echo $i; done
```

I get a similar result:

```
"tests
-
Blub"
"tests
-
Blub
-
Abc"
```

Looks like quotes are handled before variable substitution takes place and not looked at again later.

Comment: That is my problem I am facing to and I don't know how to fix it, because I don't want to switch the language.

Comment: I hate to say this, but using arrays in Bash is probably a sign you need a more capable language...

Comment: There is a solution with eval see the other answer.

Comment: Ouch. Be careful with $,  ` and other characters meaningful inside "".

Answer (score 0):

How about using xargs in combination with sh -c '...' ?

```
line='"tests - Blub" "tests - Blub - Abc"'
printf '%s' "$line" | xargs sh -c 'printf "%s\n" "$@"' argv0
IFS=$'\n'
ary=( $(printf '%s' "$line" | xargs sh -c 'printf "%s\n" "$@"' argv0) )
echo ${#ary[@]}
printf '%s\n' "${ary[@]}"
```